# issue to create SQLite DB after installation of JAVAFX based application on other laptop / PC

Tags: eclipse, javafx, jar, exe, inno-setup

it is reqired to create a DB if not exist and then save the table. The function getConnection() shown in code. The program implemented is as:
**SAVE button event calls btnsave()->insertrecord()->executequery()->getConnection()**

I tested application in following ways:

1. Inside the eclipse installed on PC1 --> worked well. Database is created and table entries are deleted successfully.
2. Create the runnable Jar and copied to other laptop PC2 --. works well as in case 1.
3. Inno setup is installed on PC2. So, used INNO to make installer. Installed n PC2. It seems data is not created. If it is created, I don't know where will it be created in the system ? How to programatically read the database path ?

   ```
      @FXML
       private void btnsave(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{        
      insertrecord();
      System.out.println("New Patient Inserted");       
    }

    private void insertrecord() throws Exception
     {
         try{
         String query ="INSERT INTO `newpatient`(patientId,patientName,patientAge,patientGender,patientAddress,patientMobile)"+
            "VALUES("+ newpatient_id.getText() +",'" +  newpatient_name.getText() + "','"+  newpatient_age.getText() + "',"
                    + "'"+  selectedGender  + "','"+  newpatient_address.getText() + "',"+  newpatient_mobile.getText() +")";             
          executeQuery(query);
          System.out.println("Saved");
         }
         catch(Exception e) {
          //System.out.println("Execption in Save");
          e.printStackTrace();            
          }
         }

           private void executeQuery(String query) {

     Connection  conn= getConnection();
     Statement st;
     try {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(query);         
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace(); 
       }
      }


       public static Connection getConnection() {       
        Connection conn = null;

         try{           

                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:patientdata","root","");
                System.out.println("data base connection established:  "+ conn.toString());

                Statement stmt = null;
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String pat = "CREATE TABLE if not exists newpatient " +
                               "(patientId INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                               " patientName    CHAR(50)    NOT NULL, " + 
                               " patientAge     INTEGER     NOT NULL, " + 
                               "patientGender   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,"+
                               "patientAddress  CHAR(100) NOT NULL,"+
                               "patientMobile   BIGINT(10) NOT NULL)";
                System.out.println("newpatient Table Created:  ");
                stmt.executeUpdate(pat);
                stmt.close();

                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String hist = "CREATE TABLE if not exists history " +
                                   "(id INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                                   " date    DATE    NOT NULL, " + 
                                   " start   TIME     NOT NULL, " +                                               
                                   "stop   TIME NOT NULL)";
                System.out.println("history Table Created:  ");    
                stmt.executeUpdate(hist);
                stmt.close();
                return conn
               }
   ```

Comment: See the SQLite documentation: [How to specify database files](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#how-to-specify-database-files).  You may also be  interested in this discussion on [where to place read write user files in a deployed JavaFX application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294934/how-to-save-a-file-uploaded-by-filechooser-to-a-directory-in-your-project).

Comment: There was misconception in my mind that jdbc:sqlite: automatically creates the database file in the same folder where application is installed. But, the folder is write protected where any application is installed. The following worked  for me (!theDir.exists()){
         theDir.mkdirs();
     }
     System.out.println(theDir.toString());
     String dbpath = theDir.toString()+"/patientdata.db";
     System.out.println("Current absolute dbpath is: " + dbpath);
     
     Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbpath);

Answer (score 0):

There was misconception in my mind that jdbc:sqlite: automatically creates the database file in the same folder where application is installed. But, the folder is write protected where any application is installed. The following worked for me:

```
public static Connection getConnection() {      
    Connection conn = null;

        try{        
            
                File theDir = new File( "c://spm_database");
                if (!theDir.exists()){
                    theDir.mkdirs();
                }
                System.out.println(theDir.toString());
                String dbpath = theDir.toString()+"/patientdata.db";
                System.out.println("Current absolute dbpath is: " + dbpath);
                
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbpath);
                System.out.println("data base connection established:  "+ conn.toString());
               // extra code .....
           }
           catch(Exception e){
            }
           retrun conn
         }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you answer contained description of the change needed and it's reasoning (which is in the comment above, but it should be in the answer).

Comment: after installation, when first time, the application will be started, it will create a folder using  File theDir = new File( "c://spm_database"); Thereafter, all read and writes are done to this folder. This worked for me.